# Обновление значений TextArea и Label

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Очень много поисков по интернету. 
Ответа так и не было найдено.
Хочу, чтобы данный пост раз и навсегда решил для всех, кто гуглит эту проблему.

Суть проблемы :

```
Есть TextArea
В него передаются строки следующим образом : TextArea.appendText(String text);
Но при повторном вызове кнопки, которая должна передать строки + значение из TextField
мы получаем : 
тот же самый список переменных + 
тот же самый список переменных + 
новая строка, 

но никак не "список переменных + новая строка".
```

С этой проблемой сталкивался как в Swing, так и в JavaFX.

Решить не удалось.

Предполагаемые варианты решения были :

```
TextArea.setText("");
 или
TextArea.setText(null);
 или
TextArea.clear();
 или
RunLater(); - многопоточность
 и прочее...
```

Ничего не помогло.

Для тех, кто не понял показываю наглядно.

Программа при включении отражает массив переменных.

Кнопка GO - парсит значение из левого TextField и вносит его в массив. А также она должна обновить TextArea, а именно передать ему тот же массив, но с новой переменной.

Вместо этого значения дублируются.

Скриншоты :

```
1)Состояние при запуске программы
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
2)Состояние после нажатия кнопки GO
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и слушатель кнопки GO

```
   @FXML
   private void updateMessages(ActionEvent event) {
    new ListMessages();

    for (int i = 0; i < ListMessages.text.size(); i++) {
        areaForMessages.appendText(ListMessages.text.get(i) + "\n");      
    }
}
```

Как мне очистить TextArea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ оказался максимально простым.

```
 ListMessages.clear();
 areaForMessages.clear();
```

Массив строк был static, а, следовательно, значения туда лишь добавлялись, а не перезаписывались. Выход - чистить массив.

После необходимо также почистить и ваш TextArea, тем же методом clear().

На данную ошибку натыкались многие.

Решение было очевидным. =)