# Обновление Gui в JavaApplet

Tags: java, gui, applet

Здравствуйте,стоит задача реализовать java Applet c поддержкой чтения NFC и дальнейшей передачи параметров считанной смарт карты на сервер(Json).Проблема в том,что Gui не обновляется при считывании магнитной карты. Эвент на обновление gui,а именно Label, после удачного считывания номера карты создавал в отдельном потоке, но ничего не происходит.Читал про paint(),repaint() для Applet,но никакой информации не нашел.

Comment: Ищи что-то вроде invalidate()

Comment: Неужели еще кто то пишет апплеты?

Answer (score 1):

Когда писал апплет для ВКонтакте также наткнулся на эту проблему, решение оказалось очевидным :

```
вызовите метод .clear(); от вашего label
а также почистите переменные\массивы которые должны заполнять ваш label
```

Никакие потоки не понадобятся)

Comment: Не помогло(Дело в том,что перед Label.setText(cardNumber) создаётся экземпляр класса Card от java SmartCard,где и идёт работа с картами,булевы всякие типа на Прислонилась ли карта,с какого типа считывателя считывать и т.д.!Может вот этот объект Card и мешает,потому что до его инициализации .setText() срабатывает,а строчкой ниже уже нет.Пробовал делать Card.disconnect(true),Card=null,System.gs() ,пробовал в отдельном потоке все это сделать,но увы(

Comment: @GoodRA вот такая проблема была у меня https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708812/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-textarea-%D0%B8-label/708819#708819